# Capturing local https packets

Tags: wireshark, https, web-services

I am using RawCap to captures local HTTP trafic for a web service client Application, when I change to HTTPS mode I could not capture the packets with RawCap, is there any mean to do that?

Comment: Are you looking at the correct port?

Comment: How to define a specific port with RawCap? I am sending on 8443, using command RawCap.exe 127.0.0.1 localhost_capture.pcap